# how can I listen to the left and right arrow keys?

Tags: javafx

When a window gains focus, how can I listen to the left and right arrow keys? I found that the left and right arrow keys are used to move the focus, which prevents me from listening to them. I don't want to use the `focusTraversable` property

update:

I aim to set up event listeners to detect both the pressing and releasing of the left and right directional keys, with the exception that such events should not be intercepted if the focus is currently within a text input field (textfield).

minimal reproducible example：

fxml:

```xml
<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
           fx:id="rootPane"
           fx:controller="club.xiaojiawei.test.FocusTest"
           prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <fx:define>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="toggleGroup"/>
    </fx:define>
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20">
        <ToggleButton text="one" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup"/>
        <ToggleButton text="two" toggleGroup="$toggleGroup"/>
        <TextField fx:id="textField"/>
        <Button text="search"/>
        <ScrollPane style="-fx-background: red" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="200"/>
    </HBox>
</StackPane>
```

controller:

```java
    public TextField textField;
    public StackPane rootPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        textField.sceneProperty().addListener((observableValue, scene, t1) -> {
            if (t1 != null){
                t1.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
                    System.out.println("released");
                });
                t1.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
                    System.out.println("pressed");
                });
            }
        });
        textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
            System.out.println("KEY_RELEASED consume");
            keyEvent.consume();
        });
        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
            System.out.println("KEY_PRESSED consume");
            keyEvent.consume();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Presumably you have tried adding the appropriate event handlers to the `Scene`? Can you create and post a [mre] showing what you've tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use an event filter on the scene rather than an event handler.  But if you filter the events then you have to also decide -> do you consume the events or not?  If you consume the events, the default handling for them in other UI controls won't work.  If you don't consume the events, then both your custom handling and the default handling will occur.  What you decide to do depends on your application requirements.

Comment: See the [JavaFX event handling tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm) for more info.

Comment: @jewelsea Have been updated

Comment: @James_D Have been updated

Comment: I can see and (I think) understand your code.  But I can't understand why adding an event filter to the scene is not an appropriate solution.  I didn't try running the code but am guessing the output on keypress is `pressed\nKEY_PRESSED consume\nKEY_RELEASED consume`.  You say "I don't want the scene to listen to it.",  I don't know why.  Can you better explain what you are trying to accomplish and what you *do* want to listen for the event if not the scene as well as why (what action you intend to take when you are notified of the event).

Comment: @jewelsea When the `textfield` has focus, the console outputs 'pressed\nKEY_PRESSED consume\nKEY_RELEASED consume'. However, I don't want to output 'pressed', meaning that the `scene` should not listen to the KEY_PRESSED event when the `textfield` has focus.

Comment: please read the help page referenced by @James_D and act accordingly (whom do you expect to add the boiler-plate to make your snippets runnable ;)

Comment: This behaves as I would expect. If the text field has keyboard focus, when you press a key you get `pressed` (from the Scene's event *filter*) and then `KEY_PRESSED consume` (from the text field's event *filter*). When you release the key you get `KEY_RELEASED consume` (from the text field's event handler) and no output from the scene's event handler (since the event is consumed). If something else has focus (e.g. one of the buttons) you get `pressed` when the key is pressed and `released` when it is released. Can you clarify what behavior you want?

Comment: Note that whatever you are trying to implement, consuming key events in a text field's event filter is almost certainly a bad idea, as you might prevent the normal functioning of the text field. (In the case of your code, you prevent the user from being able to navigate around the text field using the arrow keys.)

Comment: *"the scene should not listen to the KEY_PRESSED event when the textfield has focus"* Can't you do this using only event handlers (and no event filters)?

Comment: @James_D If I am using an event handler, when the ScrollPane gains focus and the left or right arrow keys are pressed, at that moment, the scene will not be able to listen to these events.

Comment: There is no scroll pane in the question. What do you mean?

Comment: @James_D Updated, with the addition of a `scrollPane.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this code a try please, I hope it solves your issue.

```
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class FocusTestController implements Initializable {
    public TextField textField;
    public StackPane rootPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        rootPane.sceneProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            if (newScene != null) {
                newScene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
                    if (!(newScene.getFocusOwner() instanceof TextField)) {
                        switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
                            case LEFT:
                            case RIGHT:
                                System.out.println("Arrow Key Pressed: " + keyEvent.getCode());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });

                newScene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
                    if (!(newScene.getFocusOwner() instanceof TextField)) {
                        switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
                            case LEFT:
                            case RIGHT:
                                System.out.println("Arrow Key Released: " + keyEvent.getCode());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted, perfect indeed.

Comment: FYI, [JavaFX] controller classes (including class `FocusTestController` in your answer) no longer need to implement interface `javafx.fxml.Initializable`. They simply need to declare a method named `initialize` that takes no parameters and returns no value, i.e. `void initialize()`. Note that the method may also require the `@FXML` annotation.